# Setting 'value' of hidden input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the form I am working with: (there are multiple forms of the same format shown below)

```
<form method="post" action="" class="like-form">
<input type="hidden" class="like-counter-hidden" name='like-counter' value="10"/>
<input type="submit" value="like" class="btn btn-primary like"/>
</form>
```

What I want to do is: whenever I hit like, I want to update the 'value' attribute of the 'hidden-input'.

I am doing this:

```
$(".like").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.like-counter-hidden').val("11");
});
```

But this doesn't work. When I do `$(this).closest('.like-counter-hidden').val();` , it says `undefined`. How do I do this in jQuery ?

EDIT:

`$(this).prev('.like-counter-hidden').val();` works, but if I put this inside AJAX call, it again says `undefined`. How do I make this work inside ajax call ?

```
$(".like").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).prev('.like-counter-hidden').val()); //works
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{% url 'feeds' %}",
        data : formData,
        success : function(data){
            alert($(this).prev('.like-counter-hidden').val()); //doesn't work.
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).prev('.like-counter-hidden').val("11");`

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.like-counter-hidden').val("11");` assuming only one element with that class and it is the hidden

Comment: $("this").siblings().last().val("11"); will always take the closest one..

Comment: Please answer the question in the 'EDIT' section.